# Encrypting user folders

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption

When installing Ubuntu 10.04 on a new machine, it seems I forgot to enable user folder encryption.  Is there any way to add this feature after the fact?

Answer (score 1):

bit outdated, but: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/06/migrating-to-encrypted-home-directory.html may help.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to use cryptsetup to [enable LUKS](http://jootamam.net/howto-basic-cryptsetup.htm) on a partition, but there may be additional steps that Ubuntu needs, such as rebuilding of the initrd.